# Failing to retrieve CheckBox Value Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In the bottom def, I am trying to retrieve a "1" or "0" to show if a checkbox is checked or not. When I run the code though, I only receive "0"s, regardless of what is checked and what isn't. What is the reason behind this? I'm super new to Python so sorry if it is very obvious.

```
import tkinter as tk
import nltk
import string
import pandas as pd
import csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import Counter
from tabulate import tabulate

start = input('Would you like to start by selecting a document? (yes or no): ')
if start == 'yes':

    #Document selection
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    dataFile = open(file_path).read()
    lines = dataFile.lower()
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(lines)


#Closes program if the program is not needed    
else:

    print('Ok!')

print ('')
print ('You have selected: ' + file_path)
print ('')


stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english") + list(string.punctuation))

filtered_tokens = []

for w in tokens:
   if w not in stop_words:
       filtered_tokens.append(w)

counts=Counter(filtered_tokens)


numOfWords = input('Would you like to continue to selecting the number of words to analyze? (yes or no): ')
if numOfWords == 'yes':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (330, 80, 200, 150))
    root.title("Number of Words to Analyze, close window when finished")

    var = tk.StringVar(root)
    var.set("Select Num Here")

    def grab_and_assign(event):
        chosen_option = var.get()
        label_chosen_variable= tk.Label(root, text=chosen_option)
        label_chosen_variable.grid(row=1, column=2)
        print ('You selected ' + chosen_option)

    def leave():
        root.quit()
        root.destroy()

    drop_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, var,  "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", command=grab_and_assign)
    drop_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)
    label_left=tk.Label(root, text="Chosen Num of Words= ")
    label_left.grid(row=1, column=0)
    label_right=tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=leave)
    label_right.grid(row=10, column=5)

    root.mainloop()


else:
    print ('Ok!')


then = input('Would you like to continue to the table creation? (yes or no): ')
if then == 'yes':
    word_freq = counts.most_common(int(var.get()))
    class Example(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            b = tk.Button(self, text="Done!", command=self.upload_cor)
            b.grid()
        canvas=Canvas(self,bg='#FFFFFF',width=300,height=10000,scrollregion=(0,0,500,15000))
            vbar=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
            vbar.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='nsw')
            vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
            canvas.config(width=300,height=300)
            canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
            canvas.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='news')
            table = tk.Frame(canvas, width=300, height=10000)


  canvas.create_window(0,0,anchor='nw',height=10000,width=300,window=table)

            data = (word_freq)

            self.widgets = {}
            row = 0
            for word, freq in (data):
                row += 1
                var1 = tk.IntVar()
                self.widgets[word] = {
                    "Word": tk.Label(table, text=word),
                    "Freq": tk.Label(table, text=freq),
                    "checkbox_var": var1,
                    "checkbox": tk.Checkbutton(table, variable=var1)
                }

                self.widgets[word]["Word"].grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="nsew")
                self.widgets[word]["Freq"].grid(row=row, column=1, sticky="nsew")

                self.widgets[word]["checkbox"].config(variable=var1)
                self.widgets[word]["checkbox"].grid(row=row, column=2, sticky="nsew")



            table.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
            table.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        def upload_cor(self):
            for word in sorted(self.widgets.keys()):
                print(var1.get())

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = tk.Tk()
        Example(root).grid(sticky='nsew')
        root.mainloop()

else:    
    print ('Ok!')
```

the indentation is correct in my file, but some of it got messed up and fixing it wasn't working out

Comment: Are you sure `data` has expected values? Or can you also add sample for word_freq to make this complete, runnable example?

Comment: BTW, are you always getting zero or last checkbutton's value?

Comment: I can't duplicate your problems. When I add reasonable guesses for the missing code, it all works fine. The checkboxes I select are printed out with the value 1, the others get a value of 0. Are you certain that this exact code (plus necessary imports) has the behavior you say it does? Please include the necessary imports, and also let us know what platform you're running on.

Comment: My code takes a text document, and finds the words with the highest word frequency. Then that data is put into this table and I tried to create a third column which selects the words you want to "keep" and then will make the remaining words and their frequencies into a csv. I'm always getting zeros. I can edit my response and put in all of my code if that helps

Comment: I'm running on IDLE and have Python 3.6.1 32-bit